# google drive API return insufficient resources

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am now working on a software that can track changes in google drive and get the name of the last modifier of each change. I am doing this by accessing revisions of each file and extract "lastModifyingUser" from revisions resource using google drive API.

However, I found return revisions resource only contain "kind", "id", "mimetype" and "modifiedTime". When I try to use .get('lastModifyingUser'), I got None. Which is pretty confusing. I also tried to use .list(), it still return same result. I'll attach my code below for u guys to check possible issues.

```
# Call seleted files revisions
revisions = []
for i in range (len(seleted_files_week) - 1):
    try:
        # revisions.append(service.revisions().list(fileId = seleted_files_week[i][3]).execute().get('revisions'))
        revisions.append(service.revisions().get(fileId = seleted_files_week[i][3],revisionId = 1).execute())
    except:
        print("error")
```

Part of return value I got

```
[{'kind': 'drive#revision', 'id': '1', 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document', 'modifiedTime': '2018-08-16T06:18:41.664Z'}, {'kind': 'drive#revision', 'id': '1', 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document', 'modifiedTime': '2018-09-05T02:11:35.423Z'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `lastModifyingUser` from the file using `service.revisions().list()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- From your question, it seems that you are using Drive API v3. So in order to retrieve `lastModifyingUser` from the file using `service.revisions().list()`, it uses `revisions/lastModifyingUser` as `fields`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
revisions.append(service.revisions().list(fileId = seleted_files_week[i][3]).execute().get('revisions'))
```

To:

```
revisions.append(service.revisions().list(fileId = seleted_files_week[i][3], fields = "revisions/lastModifyingUser").execute().get('revisions'))
```

#### Note:

- If you want to also retrieve other metadata, please tell me.

#### References:

- [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)
- [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.