How do I retrieve lastModifyingUser from Google Drive API?
I need to retrieve the list of revisions for some files in Google Drive. Here is my code:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
# obtain creds using oauth flow, removed for brevity
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
file_id = "some file ID"
revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId=file_id, pageSize=100).execute()

revisions["revisions"] is a list of dicts and each of those dicts contains these keys:
revisions["revisions"][0].keys()
# returns dict_keys(['id', 'mimeType', 'kind', 'modifiedTime'])

However I want to get more information such as lastModifyingUser. According to Google Workspace > Google Drive > Reference > REST Resource: revisions lastModifyingUser (and many other fields) are available from the API so I am surprised that they're not being retrieved using the code above.
How can I retrieve a list of revisions for a file that includes lastModifyinguser and all the other fields listed at Google Workspace > Google Drive > Reference > REST Resource: revisions

Figured it out thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52420759/201657
It can be achieved like this:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
# obtain creds using oauth flow, removed for brevity
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
file_id = "some file ID"
revisions = service.revisions().list(
  fileId=file_id,
  pageSize=100,
  fields = "revisions/lastModifyingUser,revisions/id,revisions/mimeType" # etc...
).execute()

